# Maven : pom.xml, cannot resolve the package

Tags: maven-2, jenkins, pom.xml

I am trying to build the project using maven in the Jenkins continuous integration for that i have written pom.xml included all the required jar files my pom is as follows

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>My Company's Internal Repository</name>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <url>file:///D:/MavenRepos/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>



 <groupId>codon</groupId>
  <artifactId>Struts2OfficeExpenses</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Struts2Office Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>  
   <dependency>
       <groupId>log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.13</version>
       <scope>main</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>ibatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>ibatis-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
       <artifactId>ibatis-sqlmap</artifactId>
       <version>2.0</version>       
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>geronimo</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-management</artifactId>  
        <version>1.0</version>

    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.1</version>
         <scope>main</scope>
        </dependency>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.8</version>
      <scope>main</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Struts2OfficeExpenses</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

but still i am getting the following errors 
'

```
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[9,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[10,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[11,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[12,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[13,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[17,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[18,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[19,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[20,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[25,32] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Action
public class FromAction extends Action {

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[30,31] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionMapping
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.FromAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[30,48] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionForm
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.FromAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[30,62] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.FromAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[30,85] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.FromAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[30,9] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionForward
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.FromAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\FromAction.java:[30,116] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServletException
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.FromAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[8,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[9,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[10,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[11,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[12,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[16,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[17,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[18,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[19,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[25,34] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Action
public class UpdateAction extends Action {

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[30,31] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionMapping
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.UpdateAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[30,48] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionForm
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.UpdateAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[30,62] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.UpdateAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[30,85] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.UpdateAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[30,9] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionForward
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.UpdateAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\UpdateAction.java:[30,116] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServletException
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.UpdateAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LogoutAction.java:[3,0] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LogoutAction.java:[7,0] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LogoutAction.java:[8,0] package javax.servlet.http does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LogoutAction.java:[14,34] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Action
public class LogoutAction extends Action {

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LogoutAction.java:[16,30] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionMapping
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.LogoutAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LogoutAction.java:[17,3] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionForm
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.LogoutAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LogoutAction.java:[17,19] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.LogoutAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LogoutAction.java:[18,3] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.LogoutAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LogoutAction.java:[16,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionForward
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.LogoutAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LogoutAction.java:[18,39] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServletException
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.LogoutAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[8,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[9,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[10,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[11,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[15,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[16,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[17,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[18,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[24,33] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Action
public class LoginAction extends Action {

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[29,31] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionMapping
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.LoginAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[29,48] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionForm
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.LoginAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[29,62] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.LoginAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[29,85] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.LoginAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[29,9] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionForward
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.LoginAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\LoginAction.java:[29,116] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServletException
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.LoginAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\AddFormBean.java:[2,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\AddFormBean.java:[3,33] cannot find symbol
symbol: class ActionForm
public class AddFormBean extends ActionForm{

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[8,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[9,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[10,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[11,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[15,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[16,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[17,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[18,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[24,32] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Action
public class ReadToList extends Action {

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[29,31] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionMapping
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.ReadToList

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[29,48] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionForm
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.ReadToList

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[29,62] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.ReadToList

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[29,85] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.ReadToList

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[29,9] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionForward
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.ReadToList

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\ReadToList.java:[29,116] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServletException
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.ReadToList

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[8,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[9,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[10,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[11,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[12,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[16,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[17,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[18,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[19,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[25,34] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Action
public class DeleteAction extends Action {

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[30,31] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionMapping
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.DeleteAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[30,48] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionForm
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.DeleteAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[30,62] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.DeleteAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[30,85] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.DeleteAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[30,9] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ActionForward
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.DeleteAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\DeleteAction.java:[30,116] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServletException
location: class main.java.com.codon.user.action.DeleteAction

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\PurposeAction.java:[9,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\PurposeAction.java:[10,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\PurposeAction.java:[11,20] package javax.servlet does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\PurposeAction.java:[12,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\PurposeAction.java:[13,25] package javax.servlet.http does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\PurposeAction.java:[17,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\PurposeAction.java:[18,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\PurposeAction.java:[19,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\PurposeAction.java:[20,31] package org.apache.struts.action does not exist

D:\Projects\Jenkins-struts\src\main\java\com\codon\user\action\PurposeAction.java:[26,35] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Action
public class PurposeAction extends Action {
```

'
please guide me..`enter code here`

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to build the project using maven in the Jenkins continuous integration

Take one step at a time. First try to make it work locally with maven, then try the same inside Jenkins.

If you have a problem with dependencies, `mvn dependency:list` and `mvn dependency:tree` can be very helpful. It's important to take the scope of dependencies into account there.

I see a weird `<scope>main/<scope>` in your pom.xml, that's probably the problem.
See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope for some documentation on scopes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wouter i have changed the scope as compile and try to run in local maven even there i am getting the same errors

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue by modifying the pom as follows

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>codon</groupId>
  <artifactId>Struts2OfficeExpenses</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Struts2Office Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.13</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>ibatis</groupId>
       <artifactId>ibatis-common</artifactId>
       <version>2.0</version>
       <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>D:\MavenRepos\ibatis\ibatis-common\2.0\ibatis-common-2.0.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
       <artifactId>ibatis-sqlmap</artifactId>
       <version>2.0</version>       
       <scope>system</scope>
       <systemPath>D:\MavenRepos\org\apache\ibatis\ibatis-sqlmap\2.0\ibatis-sqlmap-2.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>geronimo</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-management</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.8</version>
       <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>D:\MavenRepos\repository\org\apache\struts\struts2-core\2.1.8\struts.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>jk-ex-3-POM</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Though it works, it is by no means the correct solution, since the path to the dependencies are `hard-coded`.  Though you have specified compilation errors in your question, it is possible there were errors prior to it, downloading the relevant dependencies.

Comment: So Can you please guide me how can i reach the correct solution without hard-coding

Comment: Sure, delete the folders holding the artifacts that you have hard-coded, update pom to use `compile` scope for the artifacts and run maven again.  Edit your question by posting any errors that you see (prior to compilation).